# Cocos2d JS 3.7 Physics Sprite move

Tags: action, chipmunk, cocos2d-js

I'm trying to move Physics Sprite in cocos2d JS 3.7(using Chipmunk) using moving action but it won't work, I manually set position and it still wont work. does Physics Sprite in cocos2d js 3.7 allow setposition function? or i do something wrong.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Have you attempted to solve this problem? If you have, include your code and research in your question to show what hasn't worked for you. If not, you should attempt to solve it yourself first and then post the code and research here. It makes your question easier for others to answer too!

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to move the `Sprite` or it's attached physics body?

Note that when dealing with `PhysicSprite`s you can't just change it's coordinates and rotation. Instead you should be dealing with it like `ps.body.p`. That `p` has the `x` and `y` properties that you should deal with.

Comment: a newer version of cocos allow me to set position like normal node :), of course, we could use both body.p and setPosition()

Comment: Well, that took some time! '^^

Answer (score 0):

I create PhysicsSprite and 'move actions' work for this. Maybe your code apply 'move action' to another sprite?

My example:

```
this.space = new cp.Space();
this.windowSize = cc.director.getWinSize();
this.sprite = new cc.PhysicsSprite(res.tank_png);
var contentSize = this.sprite.getContentSize();
this.body = new cp.Body(config.massTank, cp.momentForBox(config.massTank, contentSize.width/2, contentSize.height/2));
this.body.p = cc.p(this.windowSize.width/2, 0 + contentSize.height);
this.space.addBody(this.body);
this.sprite.attr({
  x: this.windowSize.width/2,
  y: this.windowSize.height/2,
  anchorX: 0.5,
  anchorY: 0.5
});
this.addChild(this.sprite);
var actionToUp = new cc.MoveBy(0, cc.p(0, 10));
this.sprite.runAction(actionToUp);
```

Description code:

Create space. Get window size. Create PhysicsSprite. Get PhysicsSprite size. Create body. Set position for body. Add this body to space. Set position and anchor point for PhysicsSprite. Create action for move. Run this action for PhysicsSprite.

Comment: Did you forget setBody(this.body) function ? Physics Sprite wont work without body, i use cocos2d js 3.7, once you do that, the child will go without follow physics body